# HybridAuth not working with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, hybridauth

I'm trying to implement HybridAuth with ajax.

Code:

PHP: (will be called by ajax)

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$provider = $_GET["provider"];
$config = '../libaries/hybridauth/config.php';
require_once( "../libaries/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );
try {
    $hybridAuth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);

    $adapter = $hybridAuth->authenticate($provider);    
    $userProfile = json_encode($adapter->getUserProfile());
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{$userProfile}" . ')';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Ooophs, we got an error: " . $e;
}
?>
```

Javascript:

```
socialRegister: function () {
    var self = this;
    var val = 'provider=' + self.get("provider");
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path.urlRoot + 'ext/socialRegisterAndAuthentication.inc.php',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: val
    });
}
```

But I always get following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=123. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I know, that this means, that the Twitter Server is not allowing my origin. Is there a workaround? Is a "One-Page" signUp with ajax possible? (Hopefully yes - on quora.com it works ;) )

TWITTERSETTINGS:
[image]

Best
Fabian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all - HybridAuth and ajax directly is not working. But i have a satisfying solution now and i want to share it with you. So here is how i did it:

JavaScript:

```
twitterRegister: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.popupWindow = window.socialPopupWindow = window.open(
                    path.urlRoot + 'ext/socialRegisterAndAUthentication.inc.php?provider=Twitter',
                    "hybridauth_social_sing_on",
                    "location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=800,height=500"
                    );
            var winTimer = setInterval(function ()
            {
                if (self.popupWindow.closed !== false)
                {
                    // !== is required for compatibility with Opera
                    clearInterval(winTimer);

                    //Now twitter register from
                    require(["model/register"], function (registerModel) {
                        var registerM = new registerModel();                      
                        var ajaxRequest = registerM.socialRegister();
                        $.when(ajaxRequest).done(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            self.slideOutRegister("Twitter");
                            self.twitterObject = response;
                            $('#reg_user').val(response.firstName);
                        });
                        $.when(ajaxRequest).fail(function () {
                            self.slideOutRegister("Email");
                        });
                    });
                }
            }, 200);

        },
```

Explanation: This function opens a new popup-window. The user will be prompted to authorize the app. The setInterval catches the close event (fired by the window itself when its done).

socialRegisterAndAUthentication.inc.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Content-type: text/html');
$provider = $_GET["provider"];
$config = '../libaries/hybridauth/config.php';
require_once( "../libaries/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );
try {
    $hybridAuth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);
    $adapter = $hybridAuth->authenticate($provider);
    $_SESSION["userProfile"] = json_encode($adapter->getUserProfile());
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "window.close();";
    echo "</script>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Ooophs, we got an error: ";
}
?>
```

Explanation: Closes the window when authorization is done (this is from the docs of HybridAuth). The data is stored in a session so that i can retrieve it later per ajax.

getSocialData.inc.php

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{$_SESSION["userProfile"]}" . ')';
?>
```

Explanation: Returns the stored userProfile.

Summary:

Open a popup-window with javascript and let the user authorize the app. Store the data in a Session variable. Catch the close event of the popup-window. Then make an ajax call to retrieve the stored data (Session).